# Visual Studio: Unresolved symbols in dependent project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

I've been tasked with expanding an existing dll by adding in calls to functions that I wrote as part of a separate CLI application project. After adding the exe project as a dependency everything builds as expected, but the linker fails to find its symbols.

Isn't this supposed to be taken care of automatically? Is there some sort of option I have to give to the exe application so the dll can link against it?

Comment: Did you add a _reference_ to the DLL as well?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious reference to the dll? The dll is what I'm trying to compile, linked against code written for a separate exe.

Comment: Wait, you want the DLL to call functions in the EXE?

Comment: Basically... We have a huge code base. Many small VS projects all compiled into the same solution so things can be reused. I wrote a bunch of code for a one off application. This application now has to be installed as part of a quite. The installer requires a dll to make function calls on. So I'm trying to write wrapper functions in the dll that call the code I wrote for the separate exe project. Compiling the dll project works fine, it just doesn't link... Yes I know this sounds stupid. If this was linux I'd just link against the objects and everything would be fine. It's windows so I'm lost.

Comment: Take the common code (stuff that's called by your DLL and EXE) and stuff it in a DLL so everyone has access to it. Attempting to do what you are doing is problematic, difficult to maintain, and overall a pretty bad idea.